# problem with pdf resolution

Tags: adobe-indesign, resolution

I have a presentation on a very big and high-resolution screen (1200*5760).

I set up my InDesign file to the right pixel resolution (as specified above) but when I’m exporting the pdf and open it in Acrobat to see the file in 100% display the image is pixelated and does not look good.

Is it possible that the problem is the difference between my computer's resolution (3840*2160) and the file’s? if not what did I do wrong?

Comment: What about text? Is it also pixelated? Do you checked "High quality display" on the View => Display performance menu?

Comment: is (1200*5760) your screens resolution or the file's resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the problem.

You have made a *Web* document in InDesign and specified the dimensions in pixels (you say it's `1200x5760 px` - is it really that narrow?).

Then you place text and images in different resolutions. So while working in InDesign, you might be able to zoom in and see details in a higher resolution than you export to. This could be partly causing the confusion.

Then you export a pdf. But a pdf always has *physical* dimensions not pixel dimensions! InDesign will assume that you want `72 ppi`, so for example a document with the dimensions `72x72 px` will create a pdf with the dimensions `1x1 inch`.

When you preview this pdf in Acrobat at 100%, you are not guaranteed that the pixels will be shown at 1:1. You can't even be sure that the preview is 1 inch on the screen!

So Acrobat's 100% is not really trustworthy. And do you even want to see the pdf at 100%? Do you need to able to zoom in on the images? Don't you just want it to fit the presentation screen? You should test how it looks when filling the entire screen.

My guess is that your file is fine - you are just viewing it zoomed.

If you only have one or a few pages, you could just export a png file at the right dimensions.

Let me know if this is any help.